# symfony2 one-to-one relationship table update not working

Tags: php, symfony

`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`  command is not recognizing the *one-to-one* relations part of the orm I added after creating the entity.

I am getting the following message:

> Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current
>   entity metadata.

Here the snippet from `JudgeDates.orm.yml` -

```
AdminBundle\Entity\JudgeDates:
    type: entity
    table: null
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        judgeId:
            type: integer
        startDate:
            type: datetime
        endDate:
            type: datetime
        flagRemove:
            type: string
            length: '1'
            nullabe:  true
    onetoOne:
      Judge:
        targetEntity: Admin\Judge
        joinColumn:
          name:  judgeId
          referencedColumnName: id       
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: solved this issue.  created the entities again and then ran the doctrine:schema:update command.  everything worked out !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance, onetoOne should be oneToOne.

Comment: thanks.  Now I am getting [ReflectionException]                                                        
  Property AdminBundle\Entity\JudgeDates::$Judge does not exis  
  t